# HTML + CSS Forms scroll behind header but still visible

Tags: html, css

I am trying to understand CSS + HTML for a small project. Learning of course, and I am not sure I am grasping why this is happening.

I would like for my header to be fixed and that all the content scroll behind it. I have done this successfully, however once its scrolls behind it I do not want it to be visible when scrolled past the header. Here is a fiddle that is demonstrating the issue.

```css
.container-head {
  background-color: #343a40; 
  color:#fff; position: fixed; 
  width:100%; 
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div>
        <div class="container-head">
            <h4>Insert</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <h5>New Entry</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <form method="post">
                  <div class="form-group"><label for="id_desc">Description</label><textarea name="desc" cols="40" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" title="Required" required="" id="id_desc"></textarea>


                      <small class="form-text text-muted">Required</small>

</div>
                  <div class="form-group"><label for="id_desc">Description</label><textarea name="desc" cols="40" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" title="Required" required="" id="id_desc"></textarea>


                      <small class="form-text text-muted">Required</small>

                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group"><label for="id_desc">Description</label><textarea name="desc" cols="40" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" title="Required" required="" id="id_desc"></textarea>


                      <small class="form-text text-muted">Required</small>

                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group"><label for="id_desc">Description</label><textarea name="desc" cols="40" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" title="Required" required="" id="id_desc"></textarea>


                      <small class="form-text text-muted">Required</small>

                  </div>
                <button class="btn btn-success">Insert</button>
            </form>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated some styles and HTML a bit

```
.container-head {
  background-color: #343a40;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.body-container {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```css
.container-head {
  background-color: #343a40;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">

  <h4 class="container-head">Insert</h4>
  <div style="position: fixed; height:72px; width: 100%;background-color: white;top: 0;z-index:1;">
  </div>
  <div style="margin-top: 100px;position: relative;">
    <h5>New Entry</h5>
    <form method="post">
      <div class="form-group"><label for="id_desc">Description</label><textarea name="desc" cols="40" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" title="Required" required="" id="id_desc"></textarea>


        <small class="form-text text-muted">Required</small>

      </div>
      <div class="form-group"><label for="id_desc">Description</label><textarea name="desc" cols="40" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" title="Required" required="" id="id_desc"></textarea>


        <small class="form-text text-muted">Required</small>

      </div>
      <div class="form-group"><label for="id_desc">Description</label><textarea name="desc" cols="40" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" title="Required" required="" id="id_desc"></textarea>


        <small class="form-text text-muted">Required</small>

      </div>
      <div class="form-group"><label for="id_desc">Description</label><textarea name="desc" cols="40" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" title="Required" required="" id="id_desc"></textarea>


        <small class="form-text text-muted">Required</small>

      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-success">Insert</button>
    </form>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this but keep that spacing between the top of the page and the container? So the container isn't flush with the top page?

Comment: I will look into it and let you know in 5 mins. :)

Comment: Updated please check

Comment: Thanks! Works great

Answer (score 1):

You've probably forgotten to reset margin.

You can put a code block like this to the very start of your CSS file or inside your `<style>` tag.

```
* { margin: 0; }
```

This basically resets the margin of all the elements in the first place.

Many website developers do this once they started a new project. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy fix, just add the following rule to `.container-head`: `top: 0px;` This means that it will be at the very top of the page, and you can't see anything behind it because the viewport ends!